# Cartoon series with kids travelling through a portal in their laundry closet

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

A cartoon series that I don't know the name of - I remember that there were 3 or 4 kids that traveled to a different world through a portal which you could access through their laundry closet and each of them had their own creature in that world. But I don't know anything else about it - please help identify it.

Comment: Two things. First please clean this up. We'd like to help you, but it doesn't look like you've put much thought behind this. Second, if you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps.

Comment: Not *The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe*?

Comment: What do you mean by "each of them had their own creature in that world"? What creature and how did they own those creatures?